# Traversing Graph and filtering

Tags: java, orientdb

I am trying to query/traverse an orientDB graph, and can't figure out how to filter during the traversal.

```
OTraverse traverse = txGraph.traverse(); 
        traverse.setMaxDepth(3);
        for(OIdentifiable obj : traverse.fields("in_friend","in","out","out_friend").target(new ORecordId("#15:8")).predicate(new OCommandPredicate(){

            public Object evaluate(OIdentifiable iRecord, ODocument arg1, OCommandContext arg0) {
                Vertex v = txGraph.getVertex( iRecord.getIdentity());
                if (iRecord.getClass().equals("person") || (v.getProperty("test")!= null && v.getProperty("test").toString().equals("continue"))){

                    log.println(v.getProperty("test").toString());
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
```

This code begins traversal at node #15:8 (a person) and follows along all Edges of type "friend". I am not entirely sure I am doing this right, but the results look correct (until I include the predicate-function)

What I would like to do now, is follow only those edges that are of type "friend" AND have a property "test" with value "continue"

Using the predicate as in the code here will stop the traversal immediately when it comes across any Vertex or any Edge not meeting the conditions.

Is there a way to make it just not follow those specific edges but continue searching the graph along other edges?

ETA: I was trying to do this in Java and would prefer it that way; am open to being told why I shouldn't, tough.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems here:

1. you are not sure that current `iRecord` is a vertex (it could be an edge), so the following does not make much sense:

   ```
    Vertex v = txGraph.getVertex( iRecord.getIdentity());
   ```
2. you are checking `.getClass()`, but it returns the Java class of iRecord, that is just ODocument probably. Try to change your code as follows:

   ```
   ODocument doc = iRecord.getRecord();
   String className = doc.getSchemaClass().getName();
   Object prop = doc.field("test");
   if (className.equalsIgnoreCase("person") || (prop != null && prop.toString().equals("continue"))){
        return true;
   }
   ```